# Divide elements of an array and process parallelly in chunks using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, parallel-processing, executorservice

I have two arrays , one is having around 2000 records and other is having only only 6 records(containing access tokens). I want to divide the big array in chunks of 100 and assign one access token from other array to process these 100 records and continue to do like this until all 2000 records gets processed. After the last access token is mapped to 100 records, the next set of 100 records should map again to the first token(I implemented a round robin iterator to keep on fetching tokens from tokens list). I did try to implement it through an executor service by creating a threadpool of (bigarray.length / 100). But looks like I am doing something wrong with my multithreading logic as I am able to process all the ids and print it, but while saving in database using spring jpa system is crashing,getting hanged and giving out memory errors :

```
Out of Memory error
Java heap space
HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=52s882ms437µs947ns).
2020-06-07 13:02:04.195  WARN 8214 --- [ool-1-thread-18] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2020-06-07 13:02:04.196  WARN 8214 --- [ool-1-thread-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
```

==========================================================================

```
private void processIds(MyService service, long[] ids, List<Tokens> tokens) {

        int threadsCount = (int)ids.length / 100;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsCount);
        RoundRobinUtil<Tokens> tokensIterator = new RoundRobinUtil<Tokens>();
        tokensIterator.setInputList(tokens);

        int k = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while(k <= ids.length){
            long[] newIds = new long[100];


            int iterationLength = (ids.length - k) < 100 ? (ids.length - k) : 100;
            for(int i = 0; i<iterationLength; i++, j++){
                newIds[i] = ids[j];  //fetch 100 elements from big array and create a new array //of 100 elements
            }

            executorService.execute(new MyThread(newIds, service, repo, tokensIterator.iterator().next()));   // assigning each 100 elements of the big array to a token //for processing in an independent thread 

            k = k + iterationLength;
       }
    executorService.shutdown();
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
Class MyThread extends Thread {
      private long[] ids;
      private Service service;
      private Repository repo;
      private Token token;

      @Override
      public void run() {
        //process all the 100 ids of array with a token
         UserDetails entity = new UserDetails;
         ResponseList<User> details = service.fetchDetails(ids);
         for(User u : details) {
             entity.setName(u.getName);
             repo.save(entity);
         } 
        //save details of 100 ids to database 
      }

}
```

Let me know if the approach is ok or please suggest some better ways to handle this.
Thanks!

Comment: see #4 below for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

1) It's considered good practice to wait for the executorService to shutdown as it might be running in the background otherwise: see `awaitTermination` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

2) I wouldn't let variable names like i, k and j pass my code review ;-)

3) Please use System.arraycopy(array, 0, n, 0, n) instead of the for loop. It's considerably faster.

4) I would replace the "threadCount" variable with more reasonable heuristic. This could produce unwanted results if you pass a list of ids that is long.

I find this most efficient in our system:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(runtime.availableProcessors());
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped in using the system resources effectively and in turn not making my system hang.

Answer (score 0):

Few things which i tried to optimize my code and now its fetching the results very fast and system is also not getting stuck :

1. converted arrays of 100 elements in list of 100 elements and assign each list in a hashmap. ArrayList always performs better than Arrays.

`idList = Arrays.stream(ids.getIDs()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()); listMap.put(listMap.size()+1, idList);`

2. Updated processIds method and added some parallel processing in it with the help of parallel Stream APIs:

   ```
    userListMap.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(entry -> {
        log.info("now inside map : key "+entry.getKey()+" -- value size :"+entry.getValue().size());
        List<List<Long>> partition = Lists.partition(entry.getValue(), 100);
        partition.stream().parallel().forEach(list -> {
            log.info("now inside list of size:"+ list.size());
            executorService.submit(new MyThread(list.stream().mapToLong(l -> l).toArray(), service, repo,
                    tokens.iterator().next()));
        });
    });


    log.info("now shutting down  executor service");
    executorService.shutdown();

    log.info("*****waiting for task to be completed*****");
    System.out.println("*****waiting for task to be completed*****");
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   ```
3. Also updated MyThread implementation and used saveAll instead of save inside run method :

   `repo.saveAll(entities);`

========================================================================

So using ArrayLists instead of Arrays , parallel procesing of hashmaps and arraylist and save all entities in batch using saveAll are some tips which helped in optimization.

Thanks!